# Registering DLL-Functions in Pascalscript

Tags: delphi, dll, pascalscript

I am thinking about a kind of Plugin System to extend the Script-functions 
without recompiling the Application.

My Idea is, during the startup, the programm scans a folder and registers 
all found DLLs.
(Each DLLs exposes one Function).

As it is not known in which DLL a function is defined, I can not use 
*Function FindWindow(c1, c2: PChar): Cardinal; external 'FindWindow@user32.dll stdcall';*
which is in one of the PascalScript-examples.

May somebody has any Ideas how to achieve this?

Greetings - Klaus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach with plugin DLLs is that each DLL exports the *same* function name. Then the host program knows what function to call when it's loaded.

In your case, for example, your application could pass that function a reference to the Pascal Script interpreter, and then the DLL could use it to register whatever script functions the DLL provides.

Comment: Or, to extend, that each DLL exports the same *set* of function names (ie: it behaves much like an interface).